# Terminal wont render in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: command-line, graphics, gui

I am completely new to Ubuntu and I am getting used to terminal syntax and commands. When I click on my terminal to open it, nothing appears, it says it opens and I can still copy and past commands but I can't see anything. IO have switched around nvidia drivers but no luck.

Comment: Upload a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a screenshot would be helpful. But if you would rather not try to figure out what's wrong and accept Ubuntu how it is, you can still access the terminal.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd> allows you to access six different virtual full screen terminals provided by Linux. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, to get back to a graphical environment.

A good diagnostic for your visual problem is to try an alternative terminal emulator like `XTerm`, which is available through the Software Center.

Comment: Thanks, i can now access the terminal with the ctrl+alt+f1-f6 and can run commands. I needed to know how to access terminal so I can fix the close, minimize and maximize buttons which no longer render on the border of any window. metacity --replace worked for the terminal windows but I could not access any other program after I had run that command. I am still working on that one.

Comment: Good. Could you take a pictur or upload a screenshot?